# getRequestDispatcher and FQDN

Tags: java, servlets, request

is there a way to use `request.getRequestDispatcher` with a FQDN? Something like

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("http://mysite.com/test")
```

If I try it, I get the error

> JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /http:/mysite.com/test

I need to forward it outside the current context to another application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If the another application is running at the same servletcontainer, then best what you can do is to configure the servletcontainer to let those webapps share each other's context so that you can get the other context by [`ServletContext#getContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29) and in turn use its `RequestDispatcher`.

```
ServletContext currentContext = getServletContext();
ServletContext otherContext = currentContext.getContext("/test");
otherContext.getRequestDispatcher("/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

If the another application is completely out of your control, then a redirect is best what you can do.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://mysite.com/test");
```